# Nested function property accessibility

Tags: php, properties, scope, twig, this

I want to access `testProperty` in the below example, but this is inside a nested function (extending twig, it has to be nested), but it of course says 
"Using $this when not in object context".

I simply can't open another 'public function' inside an existing one. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I want a global variable in the entire class, without using global.

```
class test
{
    private testProperty;

    public function testFunction() {
        function abc() {
            var_dump($this->testProperty)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code, so the intention is clear. The `abc` function is supposed to be *called* inside `testFunction` after it is defined, or *returned*?, or what?

Comment: provide a full example including what you're trying to achieve with Twig.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fix the problem exactly as I wanted it stated, but I did fix it in my document. I placed my function outside and made it public and just changed al my abc() to $this->abc() really dumb oversight of mine

Comment: If you think this is the right answer / solution, you might want to mark this as answered.

Comment: Have to wait 6 more hours to do so

Answer (score 0):

If my guess of what you're trying to achieve is correct, you may want to do something like this:

```
class test
{
    private $testProperty = "whatever";

    public function testFunction() {

        $abc = function() {
            var_dump($this->testProperty);
        };

        $abc();

    }

}

$x = new test;
$x->testFunction();
```

Since `$abc` is now an anonymous function, it has `$this` variable available when used inside a class method.

The code above will output:

`string(8) "whatever"`